# Do Loop wait until task finished

Tags: vb.net

I posted earlier that I'm creating a download manager in vb.net and needed help with a part of it, I got that working just after posting. And with some suggestions from another user, I improved on it.

However, that particular project required the copy and pasting of each link individually. So, I decided I wanted to load a file containing the links into a listbox that would iterate and download the files from the links without requiring manual intervention each time.

The problem I've run into is that I've tried iterating through the listbox with both a `For Each` loop, and a `Do Until` loop. But neither are waiting for the download to finish before looping, and I'm getting the error `WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations`

How do I make the loop wait until it completes the current download before looping? I thought that maybe I could make it wait until the value of the progressbar reaches 100, but I can't even find a statement that would be close in intellisense.

Here's my code:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
Imports System
Imports System.Environment
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Directory
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Dim strLocation As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim intSeason As Integer
    Dim intEpisode As Integer
    Dim SAVE As String
    Dim Show As String

    Private WithEvents httpClient As WebClient

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



        ofdBrowse.InitialDirectory = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
        ofdBrowse.Title = "Open file containing links"
        ofdBrowse.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt|All Files|*.*"
        ofdBrowse.ShowDialog()

        strLocation = ofdBrowse.FileName

        txtLocation.Text = $"{strLocation}"
        strFile = $"{strLocation}"

        Dim fileRead As New StreamReader(strFile)

        Dim Url As String
        Do While fileRead.Peek <> -1
            Url = fileRead.ReadLine()

            If Mid(Url, 1, 1) = "[" Then
                intSeason = Mid(Url, 9, 1)
            End If



            If Mid(Url, 1, 4) = "http" Then
                lbUrl.Items.Add(Url)
            End If
        Loop

        Show = InputBox("Enter the name of the show")

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim URL As String

        intEpisode = 0

        httpClient = New WebClient

        If Not Exists($"{SpecialDirectories.Desktop}\{Show}\Season {intSeason}") Then
            CreateDirectory($"{SpecialDirectories.Desktop}\{Show}\Season {intSeason}")
        End If

        Do Until intEpisode = lbUrl.Items.Count()
            SAVE = $"{SpecialDirectories.Desktop}\{Show}\Season {intSeason}\{Show} S{intSeason} E{intEpisode}.mkv"
            lbUrl.SelectedIndex = intEpisode
            URL = lbUrl.Text
            httpClient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(URL), SAVE)

            intEpisode += 1
        Loop



    End Sub

    Private Sub httpClientDownloadProgress(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles httpClient.DownloadProgressChanged

        prgDownload.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

    End Sub
End Class
```

***Note: The code is messy at the minute, while I try to figure out what I actually need to code to get the functionality working. I'll be tidying it up once I've got the barebones working***

Comment: Just try DownloadFile instead of DownloadFileAsync

Comment: This is very VB6 looking code. Updating to VB.NET will make your code cleaner and easier for you to accomplish your task.

Comment: Make the `Button2_Click` handler `async`, remove the loop,, then `await  httpClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(...)` -- You should replace WebClient with HttpClient (instead of just naming the former after the latter :)